# Sapindikarana timing and Ashaucha period

Tags: death, sraddha, rites, sutak

While discussing with one of the learned, I heard that **Sapindikarana should be performed after one year**...but sure uncertainties of what time might bring in a year (e.g. kartru himself may die and karma remains incomplete), it's done on as part of rites immediately after death.

He also said, since sapindikarana is not done for a year, **the kartru (son) will have Ashaucha for the entire year**. Hence, except nitya-karmas (Sandhya, daily puja) nothing is allowed (kartru can help in sacrifices as assistance but not as priest, cannot accept dana, cannot wear shoes, etc.); and can not perform Vratas (even if they were monthly; i.e., need to suspend the monthly Vratas for a year).

So, looking for two clarifications here:

A) when is the proper time to do sapindikarana? Immediately after the death or at year end? If at year end, why it's generally accepted to do immediately after death?

B) if sapindikarana is done after a year, does it prevent performing Vratas, sacrifices, and even conducting (officiating) sacrifices (as a priest)?

Comment: Found the answer in Garuda Purana, Preta Khanda, chapter 25. Sapindikarana to be done after a year but normally fine in 12th day. I'll post as answer when I find some time.